# Eclipse Error on Startup: Error notifying a preference change listener

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Every day when I start Eclipse I get the following error:

[image: Error notifying a preference change listener.]

> An error has occured. See error log for more details.
>
> Error notifying a preference change listener. Check the log for details.
>
> Error notifying a preference change listener. Check the log for details.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Any idea what is causing this?

When I restart Eclipse I no longer get the error, but whenever I get this error I have to recompile my code base. It may or may not be connected. It seems like it, but I do not know yet.

**EDIT 1:**

Here are two subsections of the error logs from `\workspace\.metadata\.log`:

The beginning of the log:

```
!SESSION 2011-11-30 10:22:09.734 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-11-30 10:24:59.186
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathVariableInitializer", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5007ms) for thread "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.0.100.20110804-1717 [491]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathVariableInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.0.100.20110804-1717.jar" by thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathVariableInitializer(JavaCore.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathVariable(JavaCore.java:2897)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getResolvedVariablePath(JavaModelManager.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.resolveVariableEntry(JavaModelManager.java:2469)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2838)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1943)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors(Openable.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.getKind(PackageFragmentRoot.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.getKind(PackageFragment.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.validateExistence(PackageFragment.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.exists(Openable.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.exists(PackageFragment.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.exists(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getParent(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditorBreadcrumb$JavaEditorBreadcrumbContentProvider.getParent(JavaEditorBreadcrumb.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.buildItemChain(BreadcrumbViewer.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.buildItemChain(BreadcrumbViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.inputChanged(BreadcrumbViewer.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.EditorBreadcrumb.setInput(EditorBreadcrumb.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditorBreadcrumb.setInput(JavaEditorBreadcrumb.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setBreadcrumbInput(JavaEditor.java:2007)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.showBreadcrumb(JavaEditor.java:1981)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(JavaEditor.java:2883)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(AbstractTextEditor.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.handlePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.access$0(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore$3.run(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ToggleBreadcrumbAction.perspectiveActivated(ToggleBreadcrumbAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveActivated(PerspectiveListenerList.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3350)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 101 more
```

**EDIT 3:**

The `java.lang.NullPointerException` section of the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2011-11-30 11:24:25.757
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathVariableInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathVariableInitializer.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathVariable(JavaCore.java:2908)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getResolvedVariablePath(JavaModelManager.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.resolveVariableEntry(JavaModelManager.java:2469)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2838)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1943)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors(Openable.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.getKind(PackageFragmentRoot.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.getKind(PackageFragment.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.validateExistence(PackageFragment.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.exists(Openable.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.exists(PackageFragment.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.exists(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getParent(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditorBreadcrumb$JavaEditorBreadcrumbContentProvider.getParent(JavaEditorBreadcrumb.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.buildItemChain(BreadcrumbViewer.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.buildItemChain(BreadcrumbViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.BreadcrumbViewer.inputChanged(BreadcrumbViewer.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.breadcrumb.EditorBreadcrumb.setInput(EditorBreadcrumb.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditorBreadcrumb.setInput(JavaEditorBreadcrumb.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setBreadcrumbInput(JavaEditor.java:2007)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.showBreadcrumb(JavaEditor.java:1981)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(JavaEditor.java:2883)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(AbstractTextEditor.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.handlePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.access$0(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore$3.run(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ToggleBreadcrumbAction.perspectiveActivated(ToggleBreadcrumbAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveActivated(PerspectiveListenerList.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3350)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have verified this error only pops up when I reboot. When I restart Eclipse it does not pop up. Or if I start Eclipse after a reboot with a workspace that is very clean (no major projects in it) that does not cause the error, and then open up my major project the error does not pop. However the error still occurs in the logs.

**EDIT 4:**

Software version:

- Eclipse version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604
- Maven version: 3.0.3

**EDIT 5:**

I thought I would share my hack solution to this problem,
the only thing that makes my project work when this error occurs,
which is to clean all the projects in Eclipse and have it auto-recompile.
I also have to a `process-resources` with Maven. And it makes my project work again.

**EDIT 6:**

I noticed if I shut down Eclipse and load up Eclipse with a different (far more simplistic) workspace (that I use for testing Java code), it does not create this error. Then if I shut down that instance of Eclipse and load up Eclipse again with my main project the error is gone. I will continue to make notes on this to try to figure out if it is connected to my main project or not.

Comment: Did you do what the message says and check the log?

Comment: This is odd. I cannot find any log files being written out.

Comment: I was wrong. As far as I know it's in `\workspace\.metadata\.log`, now let me look in it...

Comment: Ok, the beginning of the log files have been posted. Let me know if you can make sense of them.

Comment: Well, you should post the log entry that describes that `NullPointerException` which is most likely one of the last entries if you open the log right after you got that message (or look the entry when you know the time the error occurred).

Comment: Good idea. I have also posted that section now, and left in the beginning section I had before that dealt with (maybe) the "change listener", which is something I do not understand.

Comment: It might be this or a related bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-756 - seems hard to reproduce and thus hard to fix

Comment: Which Eclipse and M2Eclipse version do you use? Maybe an upgrade would help (it works for me with both the latest versions - Eclipse being 3.x branch).

Comment: I have updated the questions with software versions. Here they are: Eclipse version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604, Maven version: 3.0.3.

Comment: @vinnybad, I have not tried a reinstall. If someone else comments that it fixes it, I'll mark it as a solution. Until then I cannot judge one way or the other. Sorry. :(

Comment: hi, your question was tl;dr but i just now resolved a problem with eclipse giving me the same error message from time to time by hiding the breadcrumbs. There's a button to toggle display of a breadcrumb bar, and once i got rid of the breadcrumbs, i stopped receiving the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider just deploying the newest version of eclipse to your machine and recreating your preferences.  Won't take that long and you'll also get rid of plugins you won't need.  Normally, plugins are the culprit for random errors on startup.

What works for me is to have different versions of eclipse: one for php, one for scala, one for java, one for android, one for ruby, etc...that way my settings for each don't mess up another instance's settings.  It takes almost no time to set up a new instance of eclipse anyway...so maybe this method will work for you!

Comment: Newest Eclipse is Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1) (according to eclipse.org) and I have Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604 (according to the help/about). How can I tell if I have 3.7.1 or not?

Comment: Digging around inside of help/about I see I have 3.7.0. But your advice of a clean install is good, not sure if I can do that here at work as it takes weeks to setup this workstation.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette Installing a new version of eclipse is as simple as unzipping / untarring to a directory and creating symbolic links or icons on your desktop.  You can then choose a unified workspace if you'd like or separate workspaces...do you mean it's too much extra setup in terms of preferences?  Look at this link and see if it helps you: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w

Comment: I meant it is too much extra setup it terms of project settings... or perhaps those will be kept inside the respective projects so I have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Project settings are stored in your workspace. Installing a new. Edison and pointing to the same workspace should convert what you have into the updated version.  I urge you to create a blank project and see what files it creates on your local file system (in your workspace).  You'll see how settings are stored, etc.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem and this fixes it, let me know.